# Virtualbox Shared Folder: specify which uid/gid to use on the host, for files created on the guest

Tags: linux, permissions, virtualbox

I don't have any issues mounting a shared folder with VirtualBox (Ubuntu server as host; Ubuntu desktop on guest; guest additions and etc. are all working ok). On the guest I can assign any uid/gid to the shared folder though the fstab file. That is working fine.

However, when **creating a file on the guest**, say with **uid/gui of 1000**, I would expect to see **on the host** a file with a uid/gid as the user that started the VM. **Instead (assume the user is johnd), I'm seeing a file with uid:gui of johnd:vboxusers** on the host. This is not what I want. **I want the file on the host to be, say: johnd:johnd**.

My question is how to have VirtualBox use a different group gid on the host for files created on the guest inside a shared folder?

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell how to change the gid from Virtualbox side, but you can use the special gid (`sgid`) to the shared directory, so that every file created or copied (beware, not moved) in there will have their group ownership set to that of the directory.

I'll assume that the shared directory is `/shared`.
First ensure that the shared directory's owner and group is set to `johnd`:
`sudo chown johnd:johnd /shared`
You can add `-R` to propagate to objects inside.

next,
`sudo chmod g+s /shared`

Any file created in `/shared` will be set the group ownership to `johnd`.

Comment: I won't select your answer as the correct one because it does not completely solve it. But it is a good approach to the problem. I ended up using an intermediate bind mount (bindfs) to have a better control over the files and directories created on the host. I won't also select that as the answer because it adds unnecessary overhead. During my tests I discovered that with VirtualBox shared folders, even if you restrict the permissions on the guest, if you chmod 777 on a file on the guest, you won't see it on the guest, but it will be reflected on the host, which is crazy...